# Returning only 4 characters from uniqid

Tags: php

Currently I am using the following code to generate a random name for my uploaded file.

```
$file_upload_name = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_type;
```

This returns something that looks like this `59c7b4868f4776.27613088.mp3` how can I turn this into something that looks like this `5vh2.mp3` so that it looks cleaner when presented to a user?

Comment: So you want to store the mp3 as `59c7b4868f4776.27613088.mp3` but make the link to it like `www.yourwebsite.com/view_video/5vh2.mp3`?

Comment: @MinistryofChaps no, I want to make it so that when saving it saves as the 4 character option instead of the long character option.

Comment: Substr the long text to four characters

Comment: @Land please have a look at my answer. It will be much safer than using uniqid().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: a good point from [salathe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113938/salathe) in the comments:

> The first 8 characters of the uniqid() return value (minus any provided prefix) represent the Unix timestamp at the time of the function call. Using only the first 4 characters means that the value will only change every 2^16 seconds (~18 hours). For example, if this code were executed at any time between (and including) 2017-09-24T00:44:48Z and 2017-09-24T18:57:03Z it would return the same "unique" value.

You <s>may</s> will have collision issues with only four characters considering the first 4 values will only change around every 18 hours (assuming you are calling this script at least 2 two times within 18 hours).

Using the last four characters would be more 'unique'.
If you need to use the `uniq` function you can use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

```
$unique = uniqid('', true);
$file_name = substr($unique, strlen($unique) - 4, strlen($unique));
$file_upload_name = $file_name . "." . $file_type;
```

Be aware having videos with only four characters lessens the uniqueness of video IDs and increases the collision rate of a generated file name being the same.

Comment: Keep in mind this generates a string based on the time. And if someone calls this function within a few seconds the output will be the same, see here 10 outputs within 5 seconds are all the same. https://3v4l.org/dUSET

Comment: @Andreas is correct and I noticed this myself too I should of added an edit, I will now.

Comment: Further to @Andreas's comment... The first 8 characters of the `uniqid()` return value (minus any provided prefix) represent the Unix timestamp at the time of the function call.  Using only the first 4 characters means that the value will only change every 2^16 seconds (~18 hours). For example, if this code were executed at any time between (and including) `2017-09-24T00:44:48Z` and `2017-09-24T18:57:03Z` it would return the same "unique" value.

Comment: A better approach would be to use the four last characters. Not perfect but better. I still got 99 of 100, meaning one duplicate on this: https://3v4l.org/UQ28l

Comment: @salathe and Andreas great input and I have added your points to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a unique four char name.
It will generate a random name and see if it already exists, if it does generate a new.
Else echo it.

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$shuffled = substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,4);
While(file_exists($shuffled.".mp3"){
    $shuffled = substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,4);
}

Echo $shuffled.".mp3";
```